# Move surface with mouse motion in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, motion

I'm trying to move a surface represented by an image on disk with mouse motion in pygame, here's my code :

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOW_SIZE = (600, 400)
FPS = 60


class System:
    def __init__(self, screen, surface):
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = pygame.transform.scale(surface, (WINDOW_SIZE[0] * 2, WINDOW_SIZE[1] * 2))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def run(self):
        running = True
        moving = False
        offset_x = 0
        offset_y = 0

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                        if self.surface.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                            moving = True
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    moving = False
                elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION and moving:
                    offset_x = event.rel[0]
                    offset_y = event.rel[1]
                elif event.type == MOUSEWHEEL:
                    offset_y -= event.y * 50

            self.screen.fill((105, 212, 229))

            self.screen.blit(self.surface, (offset_x, offset_y))

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)


def run_system(screen, surface):
    system = System(screen, surface)
    system.run()


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
surface = pygame.image.load('image.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_system(screen, surface)
```

The surface doesn't move properly. It shakes rapidly when I move mouse. I'm using `event.rel` to get relative movement. Maybe it is not the right way to do it. Have you another method ?
P.S. : I also press space key to activate movement (`moving` variable) but it is not the problem, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake :

Replace :

```
offset_x = event.rel[0]
offset_y = event.rel[1]
```

With :

```
offset_x += event.rel[0]
offset_y += event.rel[1]
```